# Lógica "por unidade" em java

Tags: java, lógica

Como pode ser um método para retornar o seguinte:

Sabendo que 220 equivale a 0.3275 e que a cada acréscimo de 0,0049 no valor de 0.3275, aumentara em uma unidade os 220, ou a cada decréscimo de 0.0049 no valor de 0.3275 reduzira em uma unidade os 220. Como montar um método que receba o valor de 0.3275, por exemplo e me retorne 220, tendo este fator de 0.0049?

Comment: Primeiro, escreva a fórmula matemática disso. Depois pensa na linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar do problema ser um problema de lógica de programação e não em si de programação, fiz um exemplo de código para você adaptar.

```
    public int calcula(double valor) {
            double unidade = 0.0049; // valor da unidade
            double valorFixo = 0.3275; // valor correspondente a 220 

            // captura a diferença e soma com o 220
            return (int) ((valor - valorFixo ) / unidade) + 220;
    }
```

**Explicando o código:**

Primeiro deve-se obter a diferença entre o valor informado e o valor que temos

```
    (valor - 0.3275)
```

Após isto é necessário saber qual a quantidade de unidades esse valor representa

```
    (valor - 0.3275) / 0.0049
```

Então basta somar no valor de 220 e terá o valor que quer

```
    ((valor - 0.3275) / 0.0049) + 220
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxílio! Era isso que eu precisava, estou tentando ler um sensor de tensão com arduino,  e a linguagem é similar ao java, com essa lógica e o método que você me passou, funcionou aqui. Valeu!!